# In core data NSFetchRequest, getting NSInvalidArgumentException, unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: xcode, core-data

The code is as follows (I isolated it through print statements, the error happens in these lines):

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Group>(entityName: "Group")
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: false)]
let groups = try! context.fetch(request)
```

Notes (edited):

- SQLite backing store
- XCode 12.3

I have checked the basics, there exists a `Group` entity with an `id` field.

Even if there is a simple solution, would be also very grateful for a bug-fixing strategy here. Is there some way I can read through documentation to figure this out myself?

Full Stack Trace:

```
2020-12-31 08:01:35.180433-0700 Things[25892:958568] -[__NSConcreteUUID compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000367a9e0
2020-12-31 08:01:35.190552-0700 Things[25892:958568] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSConcreteUUID compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000367a9e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20420af6 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177e78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2042f6f7 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20425036 ___forwarding___ + 1489
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20427068 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff2084132b _NSCompareObject + 46
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203aa09d __CFSimpleMergeSort + 74
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203aa133 __CFSimpleMergeSort + 224
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a9c4a CFSortIndexes + 395
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203aa5f6 CFMergeSortArray + 288
    10  Foundation                          0x00007fff208419d1 _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 558
    11  Foundation                          0x00007fff20841bbe -[NSArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:] + 232
    12  CoreData                            0x00007fff25113c7e -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 4353
    13  libswiftCoreData.dylib              0x00007fff54a88993 $sSo22NSManagedObjectContextC8CoreDataE5fetchySayxGSo14NSFetchRequestCyxGKSo0gH6ResultRzlF + 51
    14  Things                              0x00000001048b7bdf $s6Things5GroupC6getAll7contextSayACGSo22NSManagedObjectContextC_tFZ + 591
    15  Things                              0x0000000104872da7 $s6Things16thingDataToThing2td7contextAA0E0CAA0eC0V_So22NSManagedObjectContextCtF + 1399
    16  Things                              0x00000001048836e5 $s6Things9APIServerC14syncWithRemote7context8callbackySo22NSManagedObjectContextC_yyctF14completionBothL_10groupDatas05thingN0ySayAA9GroupDataVG_SayAA05ThingQ0VGtF0O6MapperL_2tdAA0R0CAP_tF + 37
    17  Things                              0x0000000104883908 $s6Things9ThingDataVAA0B0Cs5Error_pIggozo_AcEsAF_pIegnrzo_TR + 56
    18  Things                              0x000000010488b034 $s6Things9ThingDataVAA0B0Cs5Error_pIggozo_AcEsAF_pIegnrzo_TRTA + 20
    19  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00007fff2f8edfe2 $sSlsE3mapySayqd__Gqd__7ElementQzKXEKlF + 674
    20  Things                              0x000000010488313f $s6Things9APIServerC14syncWithRemote7context8callbackySo22NSManagedObjectContextC_yyctF14completionBothL_10groupDatas05thingN0ySayAA9GroupDataVG_SayAA05ThingQ0VGtF + 3855
    21  Things                              0x0000000104883b0c $s6Things9APIServerC14syncWithRemote7context8callbackySo22NSManagedObjectContextC_yyctF16completionGroupsL_10groupDatasySayAA9GroupDataVG_tF0kA0L_05thingN0ySayAA05ThingP0VG_tF + 108
    22  Things                              0x000000010488207f $sSay6Things9ThingDataVGIegg_ADIegn_TR + 15
    23  Things                              0x000000010487ecfc $s6Things9APIServerC7request3url15queryParameters6parser0C6Method10completion12errorHandler12httpBodyJsonySS_SDyS2SGx10Foundation4DataVcAA11RequestTypeOyxcySScAOSgtlFyAR_So13NSURLResponseCSgs5Error_pSgtcfU_yycfU_ + 348
    24  Things                              0x000000010488b463 $s6Things9APIServerC7request3url15queryParameters6parser0C6Method10completion12errorHandler12httpBodyJsonySS_SDyS2SGx10Foundation4DataVcAA11RequestTypeOyxcySScAOSgtlFyAR_So13NSURLResponseCSgs5Error_pSgtcfU_yycfU_TA + 51
    25  Things                              0x000000010487ed70 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 48
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c2d7ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c2e9c8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104c3ce75 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1152
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038edbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038963e __CFRunLoopRun + 2685
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203886d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2bededb3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24690e0b -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24695cbc UIApplicationMain + 101
    35  libswiftUIKit.dylib                 0x00007fff54d1e5f2 $s5UIKit17UIApplicationMainys5Int32VAD_SpySpys4Int8VGGSgSSSgAJtF + 98
    36  Things                              0x000000010489497a $sSo21UIApplicationDelegateP5UIKitE4mainyyFZ + 122
    37  Things                              0x00000001048948ee $s6Things11AppDelegateC5$mainyyFZ + 46
    38  Things                              0x00000001048949c9 main + 41
    39  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff202593e9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSConcreteUUID compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000367a9e0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 (93AB6812-3722-4022-B989-2E1423E6E6D0) - Runtime: iOS 14.3 (18C61) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
```

Comment: Out of interest, are you using SQLite backing store?

Comment: Yes, edited accordingly

Comment: Read the error message, it's pretty clear: You are going to sort the `id` attribute which is defined as `NSUUID`. However this class is not comparable (does not respond to `compare:`).

Comment: @vadian Thanks! This helped - by switching to sorting by a string property, the error disappeared. I guess this is hard to interpret for Swift newcomers because I'd expect the compiler to catch something like this, but it cannot infer this because this isn't happening purely inside Swift. Very happy to accept as the answer

Answer (score -1):

Sorting on UUID fields is normally not supported by Core Data. To get it working, change the key path to a string type, like this:

```
[NSSortDescriptor(key: "id.description", ascending: false)]
```

Key path `id.uuidString` would theoretically be better, but this still gives the same crash as described in the original question (at least in macOS 11).

Comment: Good solution but description can change over time/releases. Possibly `id.uuidString` is a better choice.

Comment: @WarrenBurton I tried that, but `uuidString` crashes in macOS 11.